# Efficient and reliable hash for SID/PSID

Tags: c++, winapi, hash

My application need to convert a large number of `PSID`s into friendly domain\username strings.

This can be done with [`LookupAccountSid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166(v=vs.85).aspx). Unfortunately, this API needs to sniff around in lots of places to resolve the SID, including possible network calls. Thus I'd like to cache previously-seen SIDs.

I'm currently doing this with a hash table (CMap), keyed by the string representation of the SID, i.e. the result of [`ConvertSidToStringSid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376399(v=vs.85).aspx).  That works fine but I'm wondering if there is a well-known, efficient, reliable hash routine for SIDs so I don't have to convert to string?

Possibly copy the SID to a byte buffer and hash the buffer? Or walk the structure of the SID itself via other APIs?

Comment: How many SIDs are you talking about (such that you expect it to make a measurable difference)?

Comment: A SID consists of several [SID Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379597.aspx), where the last component consists of a **variable** number of subauthority values. Since this component can be arbitrarily long, a string representation is likely your best option.

Comment: Hashing the SID as a set of bytes should work perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store the bytes of the SID structure. The length of the SID structure is variable, so you must first retrieve it using the [GetLengthSid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446642(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Here is an implementation in Qt I use, for storing the value in a [QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html).

```
PSID sid = ...

// retreive the length in bytes of the sid structure
DWORD sidSize = GetLengthSid(sid);

// check that sidSize fits into QByteArray::fromRawData
Q_ASSERT(sidSize <= INT_MAX);

QByteArray baSid = QByteArray::fromRawData((char *) sid, sidSize);
```

`QByteArray::fromRawData` only wraps the data without doing a copy. If you want a copy, use the constructor `QByteArray::QByteArray(const char *data, int size = -1)`.

You can then store the byte array in any of the Qt containers, like [QSet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qset.html).

Please note that `GetLengthSid` returns `DWORD` (which is defined as `unsigned long` on my system) and `fromRawData` accepts an `int`. I did never have any problems with that conversation, but I included a test that the value is not too large, the `INT_MAX` macro is from the `climits` header.

The byte array can be easily transformed back to a `PSID` using `constData` if it has been constructed `fromRawData`.

```
PSID sid = (PSID) baSid.constData();
```

I have not tested `constData` when not constructed `fromRawData`, but the documentation states :

> The data is '\0'-terminated unless the QByteArray object was created
>   from raw data.

Unfortunately this code depends on the Qt framework, but it should also work with other containers, for example `std::vector`.